# An efficient Beta-Equivalence algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, lambda-calculus

Is there an efficient algorithm to determine if two terms are beta-equivalent? I'm specifically curious about simply-typed-lambda-calculus, so you can assume both terms have a finite, well-defined beta normal form.

I know a simple algorithm:

1. Compute the beta normal form for each term.
2. Confirm that the two BNFs are alpha-equivalent.

But it is possible for BNFs to be exponentially larger than the original Term. Is it possible check the equivalence of Terms S and T in O(|S| + |T|) time?

Comment: I would post this on theoretical computer science

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because t was [re-asked](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/47185/an-efficient-beta-equivalence-algorithm) and answered on [cstheory.se].